# Build time is too long in Xcode 8.3 with swift 3 in particular file

Tags: ios, swift3, cfpdf, xcode8

Im using `Xcode 8.3` with `Swift 3`. I have written one method named `pdfFromData(data:)` to form the `pdf document` from the `Data`, whenever I build my project its not getting build due to this method, means the compiler is got stopped/hanged when it start compile particular file where I coded `pdfFromData(data:)` method(In `Xcode 8.2` with `Swift 3` it worked fine). Whenever i comment this method and build means everything working fine.

```
func pdfFromData(data: Data) -> CGPDFDocument? { // Form pdf document from the data.

    if let pdfData = data as? CFData {
        if let provider = CGDataProvider(data: pdfData) {
            let pdfDocument = CGPDFDocument(provider)
            return pdfDocument
        }
    }
    return nil

}
```

What's wrong with this method?. I want to build my project with this method as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but you might want to consider using `guard let ...` instead of `if let ...`, to bail out early and avoid "indent hadouken".

Comment: @NicolasMiari I have tried by using `guard let` instead of `if let`. Nothing helped, still that issue persist.

Comment: Like I said, it has nothing to do with your issue; just some style advice.

Comment: Does compile time return to normal if you **comment out** the body of that function?

Comment: yes when I comment function body its working.

Comment: @Karthick, please check my answer and let me know if it helps

Comment: @KrishnaCA Its worked. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried debugging your issue. This is what I found out:

```
if let pdfData = data as? CFData {

}
```

The above line for casting object of type `Data` to `CFData` is where it's taking too much time to build.

Replacing that with the following piece of code significantly reduces your build time.

```
let pdfNsData: NSData = NSData(data: data) // convert `Data` to `NSData`

if let cfPdfData: CFData = pdfNsData as? CFData { 
// cast `NSData` to `CFData`

}
```

`NSData` and `CFData` are toll-free bridged.

Please let me know if there's any doubt